# Size of a point

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I know this may sound too simple or maybe too absurd to discuss, but I am having a hard time visualizing a point in space! In Euclid's Elements a 'Point' is defined as Something which has no part. Now, any geometrical figure viz. Line Segment,Triangle,Square etc. can be said to be composed of points. No matter how small we try to make a point, it still has some size/dimension. So,how can these infinitude of points add up to give the length/perimeter of the above mentioned figures,when according to Euclid,these have NO PART?

Comment: If you think of a point as a *location* in space instead of a *thing* in space, it makes more sense. Because even if you don't believe in all the points (as for example if you're a constructivist denying the existence of the noncomputable points on the real line), nobody can deny that the *locations* exist. In math, a point is just a real number. Nobody cares what a point is, but we can talk about real numbers all day long with logical rigor. Likewise a point of n-space, which is just an n-tuple of real numbers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Math.SE.

Comment: For now, I'll close it here. OP, if you want to ask about the mathematical concept of a point, we can migrate it to math.SE. If you want to ask something philosophical about points, please adjust your question to focus on that.

Answer (score 1):

A point is an idealized object. The single property of this idealization is the point's position. But a point has no extension.

Within an axiomatized theory like Euclidean geometry a point has to satisfy certain axioms with respect to lines and planes. E.g. to each pair of points exists a unique line passing through both points.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an assumption that is contrary to your premises.

If a point is "something which has no part" then it follows that they have no size or dimension.

So stating that "No matter how small we try to make a point, it still has some size/dimension" contradicts what we just said about points. In fact in almost all forms of geometry a point has zero dimension. Being that which has no part, it has no dimensional aspect that can be quantified.

Comment: *No part* simply means indivisible. Points are the atoms of geometry. It would be logically possible to have an indivisible entity that also has extension in space.

Comment: The definition of a point is "no part", not "only one part". An object having only one part would be indivisible. And if that one part had extension, then you have your "logically possible" part is both indivisible and has no extension.

But by since a point has "no part", what is it that has extension?

Comment: That's a misunderstanding of the language used. It's a translation from ancient Greek, so like the Bible or other translated ancient texts it requires some interpretation. It would be more accurate in modern parlance to say it has *no parts*, but that's not what Euclid said. And to clarify, points *don't* have extension, it's merely not a contradiction to say they do.